# What Was the First Case of a Comic Adapted for Film?

Tags: movie, comics, history-of

I've found some early serials from the 1930s and 1940s, such as *Batman* and *The Phantom* that were adapted from comic.

This started me wondering -- comics are a visual medium and so is film, so it seems filmmakers lost no time in starting to adapt comics to film.  What was the first instance of a comic being adapted into film?  (I don't mean a case where there were films, books, and comics all existing, but one where the material was originally comics and **not** film or book, and it was turned into a film.)

**Note**: Yes, there's a Yahoo answer about [Adventures of Captain Marvel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033317/), but it's wrong.  And note I'm not limiting it to a comic book.  Newspaper comics are also acceptable.

Comment: How is this related to science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: A vast number of comics are SF&F and the vast majority of film adaptations are in the SF&F field -- while the first that was adapted may not be, I won't know until I ask, will I?  And if it isn't SF&F, we can always migrate it to film, can't we?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR**

In the category "*comics made into animated films*", the winners are:

- [Katzenjammer Kids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Katzenjammer_Kids) ("The Katzenjammer Kids in School", 1898)
- [Ally Sloper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ally_Sloper) ("Ally Sloper", 1898)

In the category "*comics made into live-action short films*", the winner is:

- [Desperate Desmond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Hershfield) ("Desperate Desmond Almost Succeeds", 1911)

In the category "Silent film 2-reel shorts", the winner is:

- [Bringing Up Father](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bringing_Up_Father) ("Jiggs in Society", 1920)

In the category "Silent films", the winner is:

- [Little Annie Rooney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Annie_Rooney) ("Little Annie Rooney", 1925)

In the category "Feature length talkie films", the winner is:

- [Skippy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skippy_%28comic_strip%29) ("[Skippy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skippy_%281931_film%29)", 1931)

**And, in the most relevant category of "The first SF&F" movie based on comics:**

- **[Prehistoric Peeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_Peeps)** ("[Prehistoric Peeps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278641/)", 1905)

---

---

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_English-language_comics

- **[Prehistoric Peeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_Peeps)** ("[Prehistoric Peeps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278641/)", 1905)

  **Generally believed to be the first film depiction of dinosaurs.**

  This seems to me to be an early [precursor](http://srbissette.com/?p=1411) to Flintstones.
- Adventures of Captain Marvel's official release date was March 28, 1941
- Superman:  [Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_%281940s_cartoons%29), was released on September 26,

---

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_comic_strips:

- Little Annie Rooney (1925)

  > Mary Pickford starred as a girl of the slums in William Beaudine's 1925 silent comedy-drama "Little Annie Rooney"
- Ella Cinders (1926)
- Tillie the Toiler (1927)
- Bringing Up Father (1928)
- Harold Teen (1928)
- Skippy (1931)

  Notable since all the previous ones were silent movies. Skippy was a "Talkie".

  Also notable because it was one of the first films nominated for the Academy Award for Best Picture

Also, if you include "short" movies, the earliest seems:

- Based on The Outbursts of Everett True:

  - series of live-action shorts starting with Everett True Breaks Into The Movies (1916)

---

There's also several **earlier** (1910s) examples of what Wiki calls "Theatrical short films", whatever that means - seems to be cartoons.

- Based on Desperate Desmond:

  - series of seven live-action shorts (1911–1912), starting with Desperate Desmond Almost Succeeds (1911)
- Based on Little Nemo:

  - Winsor McCay, the Famous Cartoonist of the N.Y. Herald and his Moving Comics aka Little Nemo (1911, included in the National Film Registry)
- Based on Uncle Mun:

  - Uncle Mun and the Minister (1912)
  - A Thrilling Rescue by Uncle Mun (1912)
- Based on Buster Brown (1902):

  - series of five shorts (1914), starting with Buster Brown on the Care and Treatment of Goats (1914)
- based on *[Abie the Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abie_the_Agent)* (comic debuted in 1914), seems to have been drawn by the same guy who did "Desperate Desmond":

  > Syndicated by King Features, the strip became popular, and in 1917 two animated cartoons were made

  - Iska Worreh (1917)
  - Abie Kabibble Outwitted His Rival (1917)

---

**However, the overall winner (if you include animated films) was a tie between:**

- Based on The Katzenjammer Kids:

  - The Katzenjammer Kids in School (1898)
  - The Katzenjammer Kids Have a Love Affair (1900)
  - series of eight live-action shorts (1912), starting with The Katzenjammer Kids (1912)
  - series of 37 animated shorts (1916–1918), starting with The Chinese Cook (1916)
  - series of five animated shorts (1920), starting with Knock on the Window, the Door Is a Jamb (1920)
  - The Captain and the Kids (1938–1939) series of 15 animated shorts
- Based on Ally Sloper (curious fact: Sloper has also been cited as an influence on the creation of Charlie Chaplin's "little tramp" character):

  - Ally Sloper (1898)
  - Sloper's Visit to Brighton (1898)

Comment: Well done. I thought I had it.

Comment: I would like to thank my kids for keeping me up so late, Wikipedia for being such an incredible resource, my parents for blessing me with near-OCD genetics. I'm definitely not thanking those buffoons at the Academy.

Comment: @MajorStackings: I thought you had it, too.  I'm still getting used to all the specialized entries the Wikipedia has.

Comment: @DVK (Using same voice) "Kids....."

Answer (score 4):

I think "[Little Orphan Annie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Orphan_Annie)" is a prime candidate. The comic strip debuted in 1924 and was made into a film in 1932.

Comment: There were earlier ones. See my answer

Comment: @DVK Using my best Seinfeld voice (when he talks to Wayne Knights character)  "DVK....."